# How to handle null variable in Flash ActionScript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash

i was trying to create enemy ai on a game i was making but i had a big problem hit detecting other objects.

i tried checking on many sites but i found no answer.

*note: this isn't all of the code.*

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class EnemyCoder extends MovieClip
    {


        var FloorObj:MovieClip = new Floor() as MovieClip;  //importing the movieclip    
        function RanNumFunc(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number
        {
            return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
        }
        function EnemyCoder()
        {


                if (!FloorObj.hitTestPoint(x - width/2-0.1,y - width/2-0.1) || !FloorObj.hitTestPoint(x - width/2-0.1,y + width/2-0.1,true))
                {
                    x +=  etchspeed;    
                }
          }
    }
}
```

the if statement doesn't work even though it is supposed to,
if i do `trace(FloorObj);` it will return `[Object Floor]` but `trace(FloorObj.x);` will return 0 even though its 516.

is there any way to fix this or any other way to import a non targeted object in a class?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You are doing a hit test inside a constructor.  In the constructor of your EnemyCoder,  that instance will have no x/y or width/height set yet.   Wait until it's been added to the stage (listen for Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE) before doing anything related to the display (x/y/width/height).

Comment: If you're still having issues, show more of your code. Including where you do `new EnemyCoder()`

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis
i tried adding it but it didnt work:
`function EnemyCoder()                                                                   
  {  
   addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);                                       
  }  
  function init(e:Event):void {  
   

    trace(FloorObj.x);`
i also tried doing `addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);   ` but it didnt work either. 
i placed my new EnemyCoder() in the first line of the code: var Code:EnemyCoder = new EnemyCoder();
sorry for the comment in one line i didnt manage to use linebreaks

Comment: That's a very poor code anyway, it's practically unfixable at this point. Start over.

Comment: whats wrong with the code? @BotMaster